# Subclass completableFuture and CompletableFuture.Allof end up not working

Tags: java, subclass, completable-future

I am trying to create a subclass of CompletableFuture, all other aspects worked well but when I use CompletableFuture.allOf, it never finishes.

the "test2 all of handled" has never printed at all - while if I replaced all TimedCF with generic CompletableFuture it worked as expected....

Thanks for the help!

code sample:

```
class TimedCF<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {
CompletableFuture<T> orig = null;
    public TimedCF(CompletableFuture<T> ct) {
        this.orig = ct;
    }
 ... all other public methods delegated by intellij auto gen
 ... all static methods proxy to CompletableFuture
}

        TimedCF<String> cf1 = new TimedCF(CompletableFuture.completedFuture("string 1"));
        TimedCF<String> cf2 = new TimedCF(CompletableFuture.completedFuture("string 2"));

        CompletableFuture.anyOf(cf1, cf2)
                .handle( (ignore, ex) -> {
                    System.out.println("test2 all of handled");
                    return null;
                } );
```

Comment: Presumably, none of `cf1` or `cf2` are completed so `anyOf` won't trigger. The fact that the `CompletableFuture` passed to them are completed makes no difference.

Comment: `allOf` is working directly with the state fields of `TimedCF`, not calling through the methods you're delegating to the wrapped future. It's not finishing because the wrapper isn't completed.

Comment: Why are you extending `CompletableFuture` if in the end you delegate everything to a wrapped future? Why not rely on the parent class implementation, or implement `CompletionStage` instead? It feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167668) to me.

Comment: @teppic Your comments makes perfect sense. Thought only method calls are involved. Thanks!